# KeyBoardDidShow and KeyBoardDidHide Using Notification's, Working in Portrait but having an issue in  Landscape 

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4

I want to use my app both the portrait and Landscape Mode ,
I have a problem : In one of my screen in Portrait mode i am using Notifications for KeyboardDidShow and KeyBoardDidiHide .
The logic for implementing the KeyboardDidshow is

```
-(void)keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification*) notif{          
if (keyboardVisible) {        
    return;  
}  
NSDictionary* info = [notif userInfo];  
NSValue *avalue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]; 
CGSize KeyboardSize = [avalue CGRectValue].size;  
CGRect viewFrame = scrollview.frame;  
viewFrame.size.height -= KeyboardSize.height;  
scrollview.frame = viewFrame;  
CGRect textViewdRect = [customTextViewTwo frame];  
[scrollview scrollRectToVisible: textViewdRect animated:YES];  
keyboardVisible = YES;
```

}

```
-(void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification*) notif{  
if (!keyboardVisible) {
    return;  
}  
NSDictionary *info = [notif userInfo];  
NSValue *avalue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];  
CGSize KeyboardSize = [avalue CGRectValue].size;   
CGRect viewFrame = scrollview.frame;
viewFrame.size.height += KeyboardSize.height;  
scrollview.frame = viewFrame;    
keyboardVisible = NO;
```

}
When i click in the last checkbox button the scroll take the images up and keyboard is shown & when minimized the Keyboard the screen returns to the normal position. 
This is working fine for Portarit mode but in landscape Mode i am unable to see the screen when i am clicking on the last checkbox button

What can be the Solution?

Can Somebody help me out for this

Thanks In Advance
Sourish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the device orientation at runtime and adjust the size accordingly.

```
    CGFloat _keyboardHeight;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] ==  UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] ==  UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    _keyboardHeight = KeyboardSize.width;
}
else {
    _keyboardHeight = KeyboardSize.height;
}

CGRect viewFrame=_scrollView.frame;
viewFrame.size.height += _keyboardHeight;
_scrollView.frame=viewFrame;
```

Don't forget to add this in viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear methods.Otherwise

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` will return `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //generating device orientation notifications
    [[UIDevice currentDevice]beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    //stop generating device orientation notifications
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
}
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: This is a bug on Apple's side for not giving the correct keyboard size during landscape.  For now this is the work around.